# R Cumulative sum based on two variables

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, cumsum

This is whay my data.table looks like. The last column NewShares is my desired columns.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('
   Client   Level   NumShares   Interest  NewShares 
    A          0     10          0         10
    A          0     0           0         10
    A          1     0          .1         11
    A          0     9           0         20
    A          1     0          .2         24')
```

I want the cumulative NumShares while taking into account NewShares bought with interest. So as of the 1st row, the cumulative shares are 10. As of the 3rd row, `Level==1`, so I have to add interest. It will be `10+(10*.1)=11`. As of the 4th row, the cumulative shares is `11+9 =20`. As of the last row, `Level==1`, so new shares are `20+(20*.2) = 24`

I tried:

```
dt[,NewShares:= NumShares* cumprod(1+ NumShares*Interest),by=Client]
```

Comment: Perhaps `dt[, NewSharesN := ceiling(cumsum(cumsum(NumShares)*Interest + NumShares)) , Client]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can do double `cumsum` and wrap it with `ceiling`

```
dt[, NewSharesN := ceiling(cumsum(cumsum(NumShares)*Interest + NumShares)) , by = Client]
dt
#   Client Level NumShares Interest NewShares NewSharesN
#1:      A     0        10      0.0        10         10
#2:      A     0         0      0.0        10         10
#3:      A     1         0      0.1        11         11
#4:      A     0         9      0.0        20         20
#5:      A     1         0      0.2        24         24
```